# obtain corresponding value of one column based on minimum value of another in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have several pairs of variables e.g. X1 and Y1, X2 and Y2...Xn and Yn etc). I know hoe to obtain the minimum value of some of the columns e.g (X1, X2...Xn), but I would like to find the Y value that corresponds to the minimum X value. I was thinking potentially some sort of key/value pair... would do the trick, but cant quite figure out how to implement it. If someone could help with any form of a solution, that would be fantastic.

```
# Make some dummy data
X1 = c(1,20,3,40,5)
Y1 = c(20,32,60,82,100)
X2 = c(10,2,30,4,50)
Y2= c(2,30,6,80,10)
df = data.frame(X1,Y1,X2,Y2)

 # This is what the dataframe looks like 
  X1  Y1 X2 Y2
1  1  20 10  2
2 20  32  2 30
3  3  60 30  6
4 40  82  4 80
5  5 100 50 10

# create column of minimum X values
df$minX = c(pmin( df[,1], df[,3]))
```

I want to create another column with the Y value corresponding to the minimum value of X, but cant quite figure out how to do it. In the example above, the resultant dataframe should look something like the following. **NOTE :** The corresponding Y value is **not** necessarily max or min).

```
  X1  Y1 X2 Y2 minX correspondingY
1  1  20 10  2    1             20
2 20  32  2 30    2             30
3  3  60 30  6    3             60
4 40  82  4 80    4             80
5  5 100 50 10    5            100
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try the code below

```
X <- df[startsWith(names(df), "X")]
df$minX <- do.call(pmin, X)
df$correspondingY <- df[startsWith(names(df), "Y")][cbind(seq(nrow(X)), max.col(-X))]
```

which gives

```
> df
  X1  Y1 X2 Y2 minX correspondingY
1  1  20 10  2    1             20
2 20  32  2 30    2             30
3  3  60 30  6    3             60
4 40  82  4 80    4             80
5  5 100 50 10    5            100
```

Answer (score 1):

In `tidyverse` you can do :

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- df %>% mutate(row = row_number()) 

df1 %>%
  inner_join(
df1 %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = -row,
               names_to = c('.value'), 
               names_pattern = '([A-Z])') %>%
  group_by(row) %>%
  slice(which.min(X)),  by = 'row')

#  X1  Y1 X2 Y2 row X   Y
#1  1  20 10  2   1 1  20
#2 20  32  2 30   2 2  30
#3  3  60 30  6   3 3  60
#4 40  82  4 80   4 4  80
#5  5 100 50 10   5 5 100
```

You can remove the `row` column if it is not needed.